# Replace innerHTML and after HTML of a DOM structure with child elements with PHP structure

Tags: php

Hi how can I loop through elements and child elements and replace the content within the tags in PHP:

```
<div>inHTML1</div>afHTML1
<div>inHTML2<div>inHTMLChild2</div>afHTMLChild2</div>afHTML2
<div>inHTML3 </div>afHTML3
```

Afterwards it should be

```
<div>new inHTML1</div>new afHTML1
<div>new inHTML2<div>new inHTMLChild2</div>new afHTMLChild2</div>new afHTML2
<div>new inHTML3 </div>afHTML3
```

The new is just standing for another value and of course there are more elements.

I know that I require to use such kind of a loop:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<div>inHTML1</div>afHTML1<div>inHTML2<div>inHTMLChild2</div>afHTMLChild2</div>afHTML2<div>inHTML3 </div>afHTML3');   
$elements = $doc->childNodes;
foreach ($elements as $element) {
//replace innerHTML and afterHTML with new text 
 $element->nodeValue = ''; //this is not working because it gets the child elements as well.
}
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```

I find a lot of information after about 2 days looking for it, but there is really not any single useful script for it.

Comment: Could you not just use string replacement in the original string? `inHTML1` -> `new inHTML1`

Comment: @NigelRen I need to get all texts from the full document and replace every word. It would be like an associative array. Therefore I do not want string replace, because string replace would always load the full document again and this would take a lot of processing time.